# Why I couldn't sign in Android Studio for firebase?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, firebase

Am trying to log in the  Android Studio for firebase creation but I couldn't sign in it's showing the popup message please sign via the opened browser and loading as long as still.

Anyone, Please solve my problem.
Thanks in Advance.

[image: This pop-up message and loading as long as]

Comment: have you added firebase to your studio from sdk tools tab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is your default browser ? If chrome then change it to Firefox. This is how it worked for me

Comment: This is ridiculous. Firebase is a Google tool and it does not work with Google Chrome? How logic...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't open android studio as a root user. Also if you are cloning a git project do not clone via root user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sign in to Android studio , you will have to login via a browser.
It is typically the default browser that will be opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to connect with Firebase Assistant.  If it doesn't work check your proxy settings and make sure you disabled all proxy for a while.

after that allow your google account to log in with Studio and you done. If you have any doubts comment below

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade your Firefox version to 58.0 (recommended).

1. Download Firefox from https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/
2. Install it:

   ```
   cd Downloads
   dpkg -i firefox-mozilla-build_58.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Make Firefox your default browser.
4. Try again to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Check the default browser on your desktop, and select one of the browsers on your desktop after that, repeat the sign in again